# Dropbox Chunked Upload returning a 404

Tags: c#, http, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm having problems committing a chunked upload to dropbox via HTTP(s).
The upload appears to work fine but when it comes to the commit I get a 404 error.
The URI is as follows:

```
https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/commit_chunked_upload/auto/37Lc6FpJvLwe120D.dat
```

My app is sandboxed to its own folder so that I'm requesting the least amount of permission from Dropbox.  Because of this I've tried altering everything past auto/ to include the full path to the file (Apps/MyApp/Filename.dat) and also (sandbox/Filename.dat), but all my actions return a 404 response.

Any suggestions?

- Edit -

The upload parameter is in the POST body.  The code is listed below:

```
public void commitChunkedUpload(string filename, string uploadID)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(new Uri(oauthUploadURI), String.Format("commit_chunked_upload/auto/sandbox/{0}", filename));

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResponse["access_token"]);
        request.Method = "POST";

        byte[] parameters = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("overwrite={0}&upload_id={1}", "false", uploadID));

        request.ContentLength = parameters.Length;
        Stream outputStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        outputStream.Write(parameters, 0, parameters.Length);

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(response.GetResponseStream(), new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

        var root = XElement.Load(jsonReader);
    }
```

I'm convinced the problem is just with how the filename/path is appended to the URI, but I'm at a loss to work out what it should be.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I'm happy to add more details if there's anything unclear.

Comment: What HTTP method are you using? Are you passing in an `upload_id` parameter? Maybe you could share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I hadn't set the content type for the POST data.  The 404 wasn't referring to the end point, but the fact that it couldn't find the upload id.

Adding in:

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Sorted the problem.